# Why am I getting "Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" when trying to use ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, log4j, scalatest

I have a simple Scala class using slf4j...

```
class BasicHandler[T] extends FutureCallback[T] with Logging{
  val latch = new CountDownLatch(1)
  override def cancelled(): Unit = {
    logger.debug("Request cancelled")
    this.latch.countDown();
  }
  ...
}
```

This compiles and runs fine with `mvn clean deploy`. However, when I try to write a test like this...

```
"Future" should "unlatch on cancel" in {
    assert(obj.latch.getCount == 0)
    obj.cancelled();
    obj.latch.await()
    assert(obj.latch.getCount == 1)
}
```

I get...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

What am I missing?

My dependencies include...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.log4j}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4japi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the dependencies to look like this (removed other dependencies)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4japi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

It seems that `log4j-api-scala_2.12` has not been maintained since 2017 so I went back to this...

```
val logger = LogManager.getLogger(classOf[BasicConsumer]);
```